# How to recognize if a code fragment's Big-O Notation is Logarithmic time O(logn)?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, big-o

Can anyone help me on understanding how to recognize if a given code fragment is Logarithmic time? I can't seem to grasp the concept. Thanks.

-An example would be great.

Comment: it's when the number of compuatations is exponentially smaller than the input size. Like searching a sorted list. With each step you cut the problem in half, thus needing roughly log(n) operations to complete the task where the input list size is n.

Answer (score 1):

If you are partitioning the input in sections of equal or almost equal length and then continuing your operation (search, sort, etc.) in only one part of the input, then your code is bound by Log (n).

---

Example:

1. Binary searching a sorted array: Here you partition the input array into two and continue your search in only part. The complexity is O(Log<sub>2</sub>(n)).
2. Searching an m-way tree: Here your node has m-paths. You can choose from one of those m paths and continue your search down the tree. The complexity is O(Log<sub>m</sub>(n)).

Answer (score 1):

An algorithm's time complexity is `O(log(n))` , when it 'cuts' the input in half every iteration.
The classic example is, of course - binary search. in each step you cut the "problem size" in half, meaning that after one iteration the size will be `n / 2`, after 2 steps `n / 2 ^ 2` and so after `i` steps - `n / 2 ^ i`. The algorithm will terminate when the size will be `1`, so that `i` which satisfies the condition `n / 2 ^ i = 1` is the running time.
Solving that equation, we get `n = 2 ^ i` => `i = log(n)`, thus giving us the time complexity of `O(i) = O(log(n))`.

Edit:

To be more accurate, I note that it is not necessary to cut in EXACTLY half, as the running time needs only to be `O(log(n))` but not `log(n)` operations precisely (and so it is also allowed `O(1)` time overhead for each iteration).
Also, my example demonstrates only the `log_2` case, but an algorithm might (for example) "cut" the input to 1 / 3 of the original size, giving us `n / 3 ^ i`.
So, why don't we specify the base of the log?
We usually refer to `log2` in this context, but here it doesn't even matter as `O(log_i(n)) = O(log_j(n))` as `log_i(n) = log_j(n) * log_i(j)` and `log_i(j)` is a constant.

Answer (score 0):

Generally you're going to find code with `logN` time in "divide and conquer" type algorithms. This means that we break the problem down into smaller pieces and then solve for the result.

For example in something like binary search:

```
mid = (hi + lo) / 2
if element == arr[mid]: element found, return
if element > arr[mid]: search(mid, hi)
else: search(lo, mid)
```

This code divides your search space into smaller and smaller subproblems. Each time you cut your search space in half, and you can only divide an integer in half `logN` times.

Something similar is seen algorithms like mergesort, which recursively divides the array into halves for sorting. Mergesort is essentially:

```
a = mergesort(arr[:len(arr)/2]) #left side
b = mergesort(arr[len(arr)/2:]) #right side
merge(a, b)
```

This creates a tree of subproblems like so:

```
         4
        / \
       2   2    #mergesort left and right
      / \ / \
      1 1 1 1   #cannot break problem down further
      \ / \ /
       2   2    #merge
        \ /
         4      #merge
```

Each merge occurs in `O(N)`, and the height of the subproblem tree built by the mergesort is `LogN` (each next level divides by two, you can only divide by two logN times). This gives `O(N)` per merge times `LogN` merges for a time complexity of `O(NlogN)`.

Another example would be something like a heap operation such as percolate_up or percolate_down. When you have data structures like binary trees, where each node has two children, the height of the tree is `logN`.